# How to specify the square-bracket analogue of MatrixForm?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

`MatrixForm` uses "round brackets" as delimiter.  These are like parentheses, but contrary to "regular" parentheses, they stretch vertically to accommodate the height of their contents.  For example:

```
MatrixForm[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]
```

...is displayed like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to design an output format similar to `MatrixForm`, but using (vertically-expanding) square brackets instead.

How can I do this?

---

Bizarrely/perversely enough, *Mathematica* provides a way to produce the 90-degree-rotated version of what I want to do<sup>1</sup>:

```
Overscript[Underscript[
  Grid[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}], \[UnderBracket]],
  \[OverBracket]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>
Even more bizarre (to me at least) is the fact that, in the code shown above, the second arguments to `Overscript` and `Underscript` are *unquoted strings*.  Somehow, the *Mathematica* parser recognizes these special characters as valid *Mathematica* expressions all by themselves.  What's up with that???  But that's really a topic for another post.</sup>

Comment: @FredSimons: My apologies!  I managed to drop that crucial detail in the translation.  I will delete the misleading EDIT and comment shortly.

Comment: There are no unquoted strings here: `\[UnderBracket]` is a `Symbol`, just like, say, `x`.  Try `Head[\[UnderBracket]]` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From very old [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdTsx.png) ([link to Wolfram website](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/TheMathematicaBook/PrinciplesOfMathematica/TextualInputAndOutput/2.9.11.html)): "Parentheses within a single `RowBox` by default grow to span whatever other objects appear in the `RowBox`. Some expandable characters, however, grow by default only to a limited extent."

The latter seems to apply to square brackets. But we can overcome that by using a `StyleBox`:

```
StyleBox [RowBox[{"[",  GridBox[{ {"1", "2"},{"3", "4"},{"5", "6"}}],  "]"}], 
  SpanMaxSize->Infinity] // DisplayForm
```

This produces `MatrixForm` with square brackets.