# Keyboard entry of square bracketed matrices in text cells, How to?

Tags: formatting, customization, keyboard

In order to produce square bracketed matrices I execute the following code at the bottom of my notebook, then copy and paste it into the text cell where I'm composing:

```
TemplateBox[{
  GridBox[{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}]}
  , "Identity"
  , DisplayFunction -> 
    (RowBox[{
      StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]
      , #1
      , StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]
  }] &)] // DisplayForm
```

I then manipulate the content of the matrix, and the brackets resize as desired.  This is fairly cumbersome.  Is there a way to accomplish the same thing using keyboard shortcuts?

Mathematica 10.4.0.0 under Windows 10.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85757/how-to-specify-the-square-bracket-analogue-of-matrixform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`InputAliases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases) (or [`InputAutoReplacements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements)) to make this easier. For instance:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = DeleteDuplicates @ Append[
    CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases],
    "bmat" -> RowBox[{
        StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize->Infinity],
        GridBox[{{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]","\[Placeholder]"},{"\[Placeholder]","\[Placeholder]"}}],
        StyleBox["]",SpanMaxSize->Infinity]
    }]
];
```

Here is an animation of the alias in action:

[image]

Comment: I find that when esc-bmat-esc is entered into a text box, Woll's method produces a non-standard font with very thin brackets and dot-centred 0's. Reformatting it as text has no effect. How would one fix that?