# can square brackets be set to 'SpanMaxSize -> Infinity', so they act like parantheses globally?

Tags: formatting, options

From an answer to [Keyboard entry of square bracketed matrices in text cells, How to?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130260/keyboard-entry-of-square-bracketed-matrices-in-text-cells-how-to) ,

I cribbed this code:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Append[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases], 
    "bmat" -> 
     RowBox[{StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> Infinity], 
       GridBox[{{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
          "\[Placeholder]"}, {"\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}}], 
       StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]}]];
```

It works OK, but sometimes Mathematica delets the *SpanMaxSize* directive when automatically reformatting.  There may be a way to prevent that, but (I think) I would prefer that square brackets acted the same as parentheses, by default.  Is there a way to make that happen?

Am I likely to regret doing so?  That is, is there some compelling reason that square brackets (or curly brackets) are not "stretchy" by default?

Version 10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)

---

Edit to add image showing surprising consequence of getting what I asked for.  Not a show stopper, but ...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in version 10.1:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]
```

[image]

Change `$FrontEndSession` to `$FrontEnd` to make the setting persistent, or replace it with `EvaluationNotebook[]` to limit it to a single Notebook.

Off hand I cannot think of any problem this would cause; I believe it is simply a stylistic choice.